# Create multiple select form with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm have question..

can i create multiple select form with javascript?

here the example

```
<select name="item[]">
<option value="0">Option 1</option>
<option value="1">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select name="item[]">
<option value="0">Option 1</option>
<option value="1">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select name="item[]">
<option value="0">Option 1</option>
<option value="1">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

and more...

i want to do this with this:

```
<script>
var loop = 3;
for(i=0; i<=3 i++){
// some code to generate them
}
</script>
```

anyone can help me? thanks

Comment: you can use `.clone()`

Comment: can you explain to me with your example, sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (using javascript):

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
   var sel = newElement("select",{name:"sel1"});

   //Add the options
   sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option("text0","value0");
   sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option("text1","value1");
   sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option("text2","value2");
   sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option("text3","value3");

   //add the element to the form
   document.getElementById("formId").appendChild(sel);
}
```

This will create 10 select box in your form, such way, you can append any no: of select boxes in your form.

Comment: ohh,, thanks!! this is was i looking for... can i append this to the div?

Comment: yes you can. document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(formId);

Answer (score 0):

> Use `.clone` *to create a copy of the matched elements*

Try this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var clonned = $('select[name="item[]"]:first').clone();
  $('body').append(clonned);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="item[]">
  <option value="0">Option 1</option>
  <option value="1">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/qkmb20qs/)